# Finding index of a value in Numpy matrix and add it with another value

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause

I want to find the index of a value in a matrix and add it to another value. How should I do that? I did as follows but does not work.
Merci for your help. result should be 0.

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 78, 55, 33 ,22])

index=np.where(a==3)

newnumber=index-2
```

Comment: You should use ***numpy.argwhere*** rather than where whenever you're interested in indexes over values.

Comment: Did you look a `index`?  Does it make sense to subtract a value from that?  Do you want to change the "index" or the value?  What did you expect to happen? @dc_Bita98, how does `argwhere` help?  `argwhere` just returns the transpose of the `where` tuple.

Comment: ***argwhere*** returns an array, so to add/substruct a scalar from it is feasible in numpy. Whether it does make sense or not, it depends on what  @saber want to do

Comment: argwhere work. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. Your solution right now is not quite working because `np.where` is returning a tuple containing an array with the index satisfying the condition. To make it work, all you need to do is to unpack the tuple with your preferred method (could be `index, = np.where(a==3)` or `index = np.where(a==3)[0]` or whatever).

In the future, I recommend you inspect your variables when you get an unexpected result. In this case, doing `print(index)` would have bee enough!

Comment: Merci, np.argwhere() works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems - ambiguity at to what you want to subtract, and the tuple nature of the `where` result.

Your array and the test:

```
In [47]: a=np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 78, 55, 33 ,22])
In [48]: a==3
Out[48]: array([False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False])
```

That boolean mask can be used directly to index `a`:

```
In [49]: a[a==3]
Out[49]: array([3])
```

and to change the value of that element(s):

```
In [50]: a[a==3] -= 2
In [51]: a
Out[51]: array([ 1,  2,  1,  4, 78, 55, 33, 22])
```

`where` on the boolean mask produces a tuple (reread the `np.where/nonzero` docs):

```
In [52]: np.where(Out[48])
Out[52]: (array([2]),)
```

We can't subtract a value from this tuple:

```
In [53]: np.where(Out[48])-2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-53-fd4087ff32d9>", line 1, in <module>
    np.where(Out[48])-2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int'
```

We can extract the array from the tuple, and subtract a value from that:

```
In [54]: np.where(Out[48])[0]-2
Out[54]: array([0])
```

That's just the index of the element 2 steps before the `3`.  Is that what you really want?

Comment: Thank you so much. It is another way but np.argwhere works for me also.